# What numeric range the mysql error codes lie in?

Tags: mysql, error-handling

I would be creating a custom error handling routing for my webapp in codeigniter and I would be using custom error codes for that. What is the numeric range of error codes generated by mysql, so that I keep my custom error codes out of that range?

Comment: it is hard to know, I too curious to know the solution if exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like MySQL uses [1000-1999 for server errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html) and [2000+ for client errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-client.html).

Answer (score 1):

Client error numbers max out at 2999, so something 5000 and up should be safe.